# MvvmCross C# xaml is there a release mode?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I am new to MvvMCross and I have just finished developing a windows phone 8 application that was being developed using MvvmCross and I was wondering is there is a debug mode and a release mode? Is there an option to turn to false or true for the application to run faster? Because right know the application is very slow, when I press back it take 5 seconds for my screen to load...

thank you for your help!

Edit1:
It take about a second for a page to load and then when I click back on the phone it take 5 seconds for the application to go back.

Edit2:

When I do an Alt+F1 in performance-> CPU Usage -> Functions I see this:

```
Method Name Inclusive Samples   Exclusive Samples   Inclusive Samples (%)   Exclusive Samples (%)   Thread Name

[ Native Function ] 409 358 91.0913140311804 %  79.7327394209354 %  User Interface Thread
```

How can I see what the [ Native Function ] function is? as it is consuming a lot of resources.

Comment: You provide much too few information to help you. Yes, if the basic setup for the project has not been changed, you have a DEBUG and a RELEASE version. But it's doubtful that this is your problem. You might do expensive things (like a web request over 3g) everytime you navigate to the page or you might have an overly complex binding. Or a combination. Unfortunately, this is not something easy to start with knowledge about your app not to say how hard it is without. Using ALT+F1 (on VS Premium at least) you can start an analysis, maybe this helps

Comment: Thank you for your comment, please tell me what more information you need, yes the application is heavily using the internet connection.  How can I know if the application is in DEBUG or RELEASE Mode?  What part of my code would you need to see?

Comment: here is the result of ALT+F1 :  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t0rbj66gx1ri1xx/AADxhl5xtNbuVAchdhSCf2TUa

Comment: You can do this using a dropdown in the menu bar: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oiwck9q3ztc4jd/debug-mode.png Also have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj215908(v=vs.105).aspx It describes how to dig deeper with this functionality. It's hard to nail the actual code to test. The profiler should help you to narrow it down.

Comment: Ah then yea it is as you said, its not the DEBUG and RELEASE mode sadly.